# Refresh page after upload new picture

Tags: java, javafx

I'm working on the edit profile page where the user can upload a new picture. The only problem is the picture display the same but the database successfully updated. In order to display the new picture, I need to re-run the application. Is there any way I can refresh the scene without re-run the application?

note: The profile picture is loaded in initialize

Comment: [mcve] please .. and no, most probably you don't need to re-run anything, simply let the picture/image be a property of some kind and bind a ui property (like f.i. the image of an ImageView) to it.

Answer (score 0):

If am getting you right, you are trying to refresh the current activity in which the imageview or picture is. If so try the method below

```
     Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

}

Comment: hmm .. the question is very unclear but I doubt that this is a solution ..

Comment: @kleopatra sorry for the unclear question but I solved it by calling new object and load the current database then overwrite the image

Comment: This seems to be a solution for Android, not for JavaFX.